# Unable to boot from USB drive (18.04)

Tags: kubuntu, live-usb, ubuntu-gnome

Running Kubuntu 18.04.

I created a bootable USB using KDE Partition Manager and a Ubuntu Gnome ISO file.

It contains boot, casper, etc. folders.

But when I reboot with this USB drive attached, it is not shown as a boot option.

How do I boot using this drive?

Comment: Make sure you BIOS settings is set to boot from USB device!

Comment: I don't see any option for creating a "bootable USB" in the KDE Partition Manager of Kubuntu 18.04.